# Keras RNN, incorrect shape of input even though shape is shown as correct

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am attempting to train an RNN to classify texts. On my computer, i have a large text file with all of the phrases to train the network on for each category (2 total), e.g

> Phrase 1 
> Phrase 2 
> Phrase 3

I then turned that into a keras dataset using

```
tf.data.TextLineDataset(
directory)
```

This had no labels attatched to the items so i used the function

```
directory.map(lambda ex: labeler(ex,2))
```

which added labels to all of the items, leaving a dataset which looked like this:

```
<MapDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))>
```

This was then split into validation and training sets using `.skip` and `.take`. Both the categories were then combined into a single validation and a single training dataset using `category1 = category1.concatenate(category2)`

I then created a vectorization layer which looked like this:

```
def vectorize_text(text, label):
  text = tf.expand_dims(text, -1)

  return vectorize_layer(text), label
```

and ran the training and validation sets through the function to vectorize all of the phrases. This then left a dataset which looked like this:

```
<MapDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 250), dtype=tf.int64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))>
```

and an example of an item would be

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 250), dtype=int64, numpy=array([[   1,   28,   12, 1199, 3445,   61,   31,  166,  163,   13,   28,
           2,   97,   13,    6,  206,  625,  972,  344,    7, 2790,   11,
           1, 1379, 3615,   24,    1,    2,   27,   21,    3,  435,    4,
          16,    1,   15,   22,    1,    3,  127,    2,   13,   36,    8,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
           0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0]], dtype=int64)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=2>),
```

As you can see, the shape of the item is 1,250 and there is another tensor which represents the category it falls into, in this case #2. I then fed it through my model where things broke. The model was this:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, input_shape=(1,250,), activation="relu", return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, activation="relu", return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(32, activation="relu", return_sequences=False))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="relu"))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy','Precision','Recall'])
model.fit(train_set,batch_size=32,epochs=1)
```

but when i ran the code, i got the error

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_54" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 1, 250), found shape=(None, 250)
```

To solve this i tried to add in a reshaping layer, which didnt work. I also tried to use np.expand_dims, but that also couldn't solve the problem. Does anyone have a solution? Also, some functions such as train_set.shape give errors such as `ConcatenateDataset object has no attribute shape`

Edit: the data pre-processing
splitting and extracting

```
def labeler(example, index):  #function to label items 
  return example, tf.cast(index, tf.int64)

train_set_1 = tf.data.TextLineDataset( #get data 
    "comments1.txt",
    compression_type=None,
    buffer_size=None,
    num_parallel_reads=None,
    name=None
)

#split data into val and training 

val_set_1 = train_set_1.skip(int(1200*8/10)) #1200 is the number of items so 80:20 split
train_set_1 = train_set_1.take(int(1200*8/10))
#label both sets 
labeled_train_1 = train_set_1.map(lambda ex: labeler(ex, 1)) #1 is the label
labeled_val_1 = val_set_1.map(lambda ex: labeler(ex, 1))
print(labeled_train_1)


print(train_set_1)

#repeat for set 2 
train_set_2 = tf.data.TextLineDataset(
    "comments2.txt",
    compression_type=None,
    buffer_size=None,
    num_parallel_reads=None,
    name=None
)
val_set_2 = train_set_2.skip(int(1200*8/10))
train_set_2= train_set_2.take(int(1200*8/10))
labeled_train_2 = train_set_2.map(lambda ex: labeler(ex, 2))
labeled_val_2 = val_set_2.map(lambda ex: labeler(ex, 2))
```

vectorization

```
#len(counter) is total number of words, max_length is 250
vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization( max_tokens=len(counter), output_mode='int', output_sequence_length=max_length)
vectorize_layer.adapt(train_set_1)
vectorize_layer.adapt(train_set_2)  


def vectorize_text(text, label): #this is where i can change the dimensions and vectorize the whole sequence 
  text = tf.expand_dims(text, 0)
  text = tf.expand_dims(text, -1)

  return vectorize_layer(text), label

#actually vectorizing and combining all the text
train_1= labeled_train_1.map(vectorize_text)
train_2 = labeled_train_2.map(vectorize_text)
train_set = train_1.concatenate(train_2)
val_1 = labeled_val_1.map(vectorize_text)
val_2 = labeled_val_2.map(vectorize_text)
val_set = val_1.concatenate(val_2)
print(val_2)
print(list(val_2))
```

next it is just fed into the model.
Edit 2:
I found a notebook doing a similar thing to my project, and it seems to use an embedding layer in the neural network, so i think that a embedding layer might help. I have experimented with it and using different configurations of expand dims, but still have no solution, but the layer might be useful.

This is what i am currently messing about with:

```
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(len(counter),250,input_length=1))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, activation="relu", return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, activation="relu", return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(32, activation="relu", return_sequences=False))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="relu"))
```

but i have also tried `len(counter),1,input_length=250`.
Edit 3: i have managed to change the dimensionality to 250,1 instead of 1,250, but i get an error message that for the fit loop the input shape is none,1,1. This seems like the problem might be that the input is both the tokenized words, which is a tensor of size 250,1, and also the answer aka dataset 1 or dataset 2, which is another tensor, leading to a tensor containing 2 tensors, which might give a size of none,1,1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Problem was that there was a bug in the way that a vectorize layer works, which would cause it to sometimes return an empty array instead of one padded. Because of this, i had to convert the dataset to an array using

```
def dataset_to_numpy(ds):

    #Convert tensorflow dataset to numpy arrays

    texts = []
    labels = []

    # Iterate over a dataset
    for i, (text, label) in enumerate(tfds.as_numpy(ds)):
        texts.append(text)
        labels.append(label)

    for i, txt in enumerate(texts):
        if i < 3:
            print(txt.shape, labels[i])

    return texts, labels
```

I ran the val and training set through the function and then used this function

```
to_del = [] 
  for i in range(len(train_set[0])):
    if train_set[0][i].shape != (250, 1):
      print(i)
      to_del.append(i)
```

which got the items to delete. I then deleted those items in the array and ran this code

```
train_set[0] = list(train_set[0])
train_set[1] = list(train_set[1])
train_set[0] = np.array([np.array(val) for val in train_set[0]])
train_set[1] = np.array([np.array(val) for val in train_set[1]])
train_set[1] = np.expand_dims(train_set[1],-1)
```

which turned the lists into np arrays and also expanded the dimensions for the targets. Finally, i converted train_set to x_train and y_train and fed it into the network where it started to train.

Answer (score 3):

you just need to expand your dims, even though you might be missing a step, but I'll talk about that later... the fix should be:

```
model.fit(tf.expand_dim(train_set, 1),batch_size=32,epochs=1)
```

now, about the dims:
An RNN expects a **single element** to be in the shape `(None, X)` with X a positive integer.
The first `None` represent the length of your phrase/sequence, since it may vary, it uses `None` to avoid having to fix it manually.
The second dimension, `X` represents the "feature" of an element in your sequence. Take for example weather forecast, those features are the wind speed, the humidity and so on.

Having said this, your sequences should be encoded as `(250, 1)` since you have "250 words/elements in the sequence", and each word has 1 feature (the integer corresponding to it).

Given this, in my opinion, you should use the following:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, input_shape=(250,1), activation="relu", return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, activation="relu", return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(32, activation="relu", return_sequences=False))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="relu"))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy','Precision','Recall'])
model.fit(tf.expand_dim(train_set, -1),batch_size=32,epochs=1)
```

you can see this written in the doc [in this page](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/):

> Call arguments
> inputs: A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature].

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but this runs into the error i mentioned at the end of the post. For some reason,` tf.expand_dims` gives an error of  Attempt to convert a value `(<ConcatenateDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 250), dtype=tf.int64, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.ConcatenateDataset'>) to a Tensor`. This is why i was doing np.expand_dims in the vectorization step, but no matter how i change the way i expand the dimensions, i cannot get the code to run.

Comment: @Mercury you can just use ```data = dataset.map(lambda x, y: x)
labels = dataset.map(lambda x, y: y)```

Comment: Please allow me an hour to get to my pc and i’ll fix the answer with the complete code

Comment: Thank you very much. That sounds like it will be useful but i don't quite understand what you mean so i will wait for you to update your answer.

Comment: @Mercury can you please post a minimal reproducible example of the preprocessing of your data? you are using a lot of variables that you don't explain what they are

Comment: @Mercury I'm not able to reproduce your Dataset structure with the steps described, my best guess at the moment is to do the `expand_dims` on the return line of `vectorize_text`, after having called `vectorize_layer`, so something like `return tf.expand_dims(vectorize_layer(text), -1), label`

Comment: @ Alberto Sinigaglia I have added some more code to try and help you understand what is going on. Hopefully that helps, let me know if you need more.

Comment: @Mercury I suppose that `train_set` is just `train_1.concatenate(train_2)` right?

Comment: Yep thats exactly right

Comment: @Mercury actually to me seems that `train_1.concatenate(train_2).map(lambda el, label: (tf.expand_dims(el, -1),label))` works fine

Comment: Also your fix of putting the expand dims in the output seems to have helped, but i still get an error when trying to feed it into the model. First, the shape of all items in the dataset seem to be 250,1, but the shape overall appears to be none,1. Second, i get the error:ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds.

Comment: Error message was to long, it is:ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node strided_slice}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](Shape, strided_slice/stack, strided_slice/stack_1, strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: [0], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.

Comment: Both the fixes work into changing the dimensionality of the output to 250,1, but there is still the error message in both cases.

Comment: Sorry i keep adding comments, but it might be useful to add i am encoding the answer in the train_set dataset. Aka: there are 2 parts, 1) the vectorized data which looks like (<tf.Tensor: shape=(250, 1), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[  25],
       [   1],
       [  30],
       [  85],
       [ 317],
       [   9], and 2) the answer, in this case category 1, so  <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1>). Hope that that is useful as when i use a reshape layer as the first layer, i get an error message:total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [1, 1], output_shape = [250, 1]

Comment: @Mercury seems that the problem is just that TF is worried that you load everything on main memory.. in theory a simple loop with `for x,y in train_set.batch(1024):model.fit(test.batch(1024),epochs=1)` works fine

Comment: I just got the message:WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 250, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 250, 1) but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1, 1). I think this means that the error is that the answer value is encoded in the data so it is giving a size of (none,1,1,)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246835/discussion-between-alberto-sinigaglia-and-mercury).

Comment: @Mercury are you sure you are not doing the dim expand two times?

Comment: @Mercury remove all the expand dims that you have, than after everything, just before the fit, use `train_set_reshaped = train_set.map(lambda x,y: (tf.expand_dims(x, -1), y))` and use `train_set_reshaped` as argument to the fir method... at least I can see it running, but I'm not going to test it because for some reason is very very slow

Comment: I just tried the replacing train_set with train_set_reshaped and removing the other expand dims, but i still just get the same error which seems to say the problem is  an input size of (none,1,1,), even when it seems like (250,1)

Comment: @Mercury please be sure that you have removed all the others `expand_dims`, also inside `vectorize_text`

Comment: All of the expand dims have been removed, including in vectorize text. vectorize text just passes through a vectorize layer, so the only expand dims is inside the line train_set_reshaped = train_set.map(lambda x,y: (tf.expand_dims(x,-1),y)).

Comment: I have also added some more info to the post